# InvalidCastException in xaml while navigate the page

Tags: windows, xaml, exception, windows-mobile

This is code of click event of MainPage

```
void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var item = ((EventItem)e.ClickedItem);
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(EventPage), new Navigator() { Parent = "Dashboard", Event = item });
}
```

[In image the code of next page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6GvO.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sender` parameter of the loaded event is the control that raised the event (in this case, the current page); so its type is the type of the page, not `Navigator`.

Apparently you're trying to access the argument that was passed to `Frame.Navigate`. To do that, you should override the `OnNavigatedTo` method:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var param = (Navigator)e.Parameter;
    ...
}
```

Comment: @iamkunjal, don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: i am a new in stackoverflow so not have 15 reputation but really i appreciate your help.

Comment: Thomas Levesque... need your more help.. so how can i contact you?

Comment: now i get the another error about "System.Runtime.interopServices.COMException" in my API Function.. told me the Invalid JSON String.